# Size of Objects in entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Pardon the possible obviousness of my lack of understanding entanglement but how big have we noticed the objects in the system whole? We talking particles or can planets or universes be entangled?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that forces things to become unentangled if they get large.

In fact if two particles are entangled, then any system that contains those particles is also entangled. Its normal to be entangled.

Answer (score 0):

For some insight into the current state of the art with meso- and macroscopic entangled objects you may want to take a look at "[Entangled mirrors could 'reflect' quantum gravity](http://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevA.92.012126)" (APS Synopsis link). The proposal envisions "entanglement of mirrors weighing as much as 100 grams", or the size of good apples, as the article points out. It seems the technology is available and the applications worthy.

Comment: Thanks @udrv !! I am going to have to re-read that article a few times over ;)

Answer (score -1):

> how big have we noticed the objects in the system whole? We talking particles or can planets or universes be entangled

The term "entangled" is a short hand way of saying "a  mathematical wavefunction  (a solution of the quantum mechanical equation for the system), describes the behavior of the system". Example  the Hydrogen atom : the electron and the proton are entangled.

In theory the whole world can be defined with a wave function that has everything entangled. BUT our measurements have accuracies and measurement errors. The classical domain emerges when within our measurement errors we cannot see any entanglement. This is described by the [density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix)  where entanglement is seen in the off diagonal elements. When these elements become equivalent to zero within our accuracies, then the system behaves classically and entanglement can be ignored. This happens most of the time when [h_bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) is effectively 0,  the Heisenberg Uncertainty is irrelevant, all observables commute . h_bar is of order 10^-34 jouleseconds, a very small number, so sizes are small and the effects start to be seen in nano dimensions ( hence nano technology).

BUT there are exceptions where quantum mechanical order/entanglement appears macroscopically: lasers,  superconductivity, the order in crystals , superfluidity. Superconductivity can extend quantum mechanical effects ( and thus entanglement)to kilometers.

Comment: Entanglement is more than just sayiong that the system is described by a wavefunction. It involves (i) the notion of subsystems and (ii) the fact that the subsystems cannot be described by separate wavefunctions (one for each subsystem) which might be classically correlated.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch  The density matrix formalism clears up this, all subsystems are there as collumns and rows of the matrix.

Comment: This is not correct. Subsystems relate to a tensor product structure. Blocks of rows/columns relate to a sub*space* structure.  Entanglement is w.r.t. subsystems.

Comment: for entangled states in the density matrix formalism see https://physics.ucsd.edu/~wucj/teach/Phy212A_2013/Quan212a_Lect_3.pdf

Comment: Those notes are about using the *reduced density matrix* to determine the entanglement of a *pure* bipartite state. In the reduced density matrix, entanglement has nothing to do with off-diagonal elements, but with the entropy of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I am not familiar with entropies of eigenvalues. I am with pure states and mixed states and incoherent states. Once the phases are effectively lost  (0s in the off diagonal elements) one cannot have entanglement, afaik.

Comment: You are thinking about coherences, not entanglement. There is no entanglement without coherence, but you can well have coherence without entanglement (such as a state $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$). Also note that coherence is w.r.t. a "classical" basis, while entanglement is w.r.t. a bipartition (but does not need the notion of a "classical" basis).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The question was about entanglement , which implies coherence, no coherence no entanglement as you state yourself.

Comment: To recap if I understood you both correctlythis holds true:

Comment: There is a theory that states our universe is in a black hole, [link](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/02/140218-black-hole-blast-explains-big-bang/) so if we are in fact in a black hole we could, from superconductivity, be entangled. But you're both saying we could still be entangled in a normal state as well?

Comment: @deFactoDARLING  In theory , with unmeasurably small correlations which are the only way to detect entanglement. Superconductivity is not an attribute of black holes.

Comment: @annav you've been incredibly helpful. Thank you so much. I am trying to learn but much information out there pretty much assumes the reader already knows the basics. Sincerely appreciative.